# Weighted Least Squares Without Intercept

Tags: linear-algebra, regression, estimation, weighted-least-squares

I am studying the WLS model for $y=\beta x+\epsilon$, where $\beta$ and $x$ are vectors and $\epsilon$ is the error term. This is a multiple regression model without an intercept. How would I find the WLS estimator $b$ for $\beta$ and how would I find the variance of this estimator?
I was thinking of taking $b=\frac{\sum{w_ix_iy_i}}{\sum{w_ix_i^2}}$, where the $w_i$ are the weights. Then $Var(b)$ would be $\frac{\sigma^2}{\sum{w_ix_i^2}}$.
Is this correct? I'm afraid of the lack of intercept will throw it off.

Comment: To really understand this you should write down the loss function and try to derive the solution yourself by considering the first order condition for minimization.

Comment: I did and got that b using matrix language, but I am not sure if that includes the intercept or not.

Comment: The intercept corresponds to a column of $1s$ in your observation matrix (typically $X$). Throw out the $1s$ and you throw out the intercept. To be clear, what you are actually doing in any least squares scenario is projecting onto the column space of your observations, $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbb{E}(\epsilon_i|x_i)=0$ and $\operatorname{Var}(\epsilon_i|x_i)=\sigma_i^2 $, thus WLS is
$$
\hat{\beta} = (X'WX)^{-1}X'WY.
$$ 
Without the intercept $X$ is  $n\times 1$ vector, $ W = diag (w_1,.., w_n)$, hence $$
(X'WX)^{-1} = (\sum_i x_i^2w_i)^{-1}=1/\sum_i x_i^2w_i .
$$
 Where $X'WY = \sum x_iw_iy_i $, thus
$$
\hat{\beta} = \frac{\sum x_i w_iy_i}{\sum x_i^2w_i}.
$$
As $w_i =1/\sigma_i^2$
$$
\operatorname{Var}(\hat{\beta}|X)=\frac{\sum x_i^2 \sigma^4_i /\sigma_i^2}{(\sum x_i^2/\sigma_i^2 )^2  } = \frac{1}{\sum x_i^2/\sigma_i^2},
$$
or in matrix form, denote $\mathbb{\operatorname{Var}}[\mathbf{\vec{\epsilon}}|X] = \Sigma$ so  $W = \Sigma^{-1}$, thus
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}(\hat{\beta}|X) & = (X'WX)^{-1}X'W \operatorname{Var}(Y) WX(X'WX)^{-1} \\
 &= (X'\Sigma^{-1}X)^{-1} X'\Sigma^{-1} \Sigma \Sigma^{-1}X (X'\Sigma^{-1}X)^{-1}\\
& = (X'\Sigma^{-1}X)^{-1}\\
& =(\sum x_i /\sigma_i^2)^{-1}.
\end{align}